# tsc not reporting errors when compiling

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, tsc

I'm having some issues figuring out a mysterious situation

I have a tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "./app/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And when I do tsc with the code below, which is clearly wrong:

```
const credentials = Config.blahblah
import Config from '../../../config'
```

I know it's wrong because Config is not imported before using it but after.

If i switch the two lines, then the code passes my tests. But the problem is, if I keep the order as above (which should give me an error), and when I do

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register app/**/index-test.ts
```

or even

```
tsc
```

For instance:

```
➜  GhostFaceRestful git:(exie/workon_typescript) ✗ mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register app/**/index-test.ts
➜  GhostFaceRestful git:(exie/workon_typescript) ✗
```

There's no error message at all. This makes debugging extremely difficult. I'm wondering what am I doing wrong? At least tsc should tell me there's an compiling error in this case?

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's not a TypeScript error, as ES6 (and, I suppose, TypeScript) `import` statements are hoisted. (You can verify this by running `tsc` - it, too, reports no error.)

Interestingly, when it's compiled, the `require` calls are not hoisted. So this:

```
const credentials = Config.blahblah
import Config from '../../../config'
```

becomes this:

```
"use strict";
var credentials = Config.blahblah;
var Config = require('../../../config');
```

and you should see a runtime error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Config' of undefined
```

If you want to verify that `ts-node` is reporting TypeScript compilation errors, use an obvious TypeScript error; something like this:

```
const n: number = "not-a-number";
```

Comment: Well, typescript compiler could report this as 'variable used before being initialized' error when `module` is set to commonjs. The code should work just fine with any other module system.

Comment: @artem Yep. It could, but it doesn't.